# Change the state of a variable of a contract B from a Keeper

Tags: solidity, chainlink, chainlink-keepers

The purpose is to use this variable from the B contract
Im trying with delegate call but doesnt work,only works with event

ContractB.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >0.8.0;

contract ContractB {
    
    uint256 public tokenName = uint256(2);
    event SetToken(uint256 _tokenName); 

    function setTokenName(uint256 _newName) external returns (uint256) {                
        setInternal(_newName);  
    }
    
    function setInternal (uint256 _newName) public returns (uint256)
    {
        tokenName = _newName;
        emit SetToken(tokenName);
        return tokenName;
    }
            
    function getTokenName() public view returns (uint256)
    {
        return tokenName;
    }        
}
```

Counter.sol

```
//Begin
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;

interface KeeperCompatibleInterface {
    function checkUpkeep(bytes calldata checkData) external returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory performData);
    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata performData) external;
}

contract Counter is KeeperCompatibleInterface {
    
    uint256 public counter;    // Public counter variable

    // Use an interval in seconds and a timestamp to slow execution of Upkeep
    //60 seconds
    uint public immutable interval;
    uint public lastTimeStamp;  //My counter was updated  
    
    //**
    address contractBAddress;
    uint256 public tokenName = uint256(2);
    //**
    
    constructor(uint updateInterval,address _contractBAddress) {
      interval = updateInterval;
      lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
      counter = 0;
      contractBAddress=_contractBAddress;
    }

    function checkUpkeep(bytes calldata checkData) external view override returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory performData) {
        upkeepNeeded = (block.timestamp - lastTimeStamp) > interval;
        performData = checkData;
    }

    
    //When checkUpKeep its already to launch, this task is executed
    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata) external override {
        lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        counter=0;
        counter = counter + 1;
        (bool success, bytes memory returndata) = contractBAddress.delegatecall(
              abi.encodeWithSignature("setTokenName(uint256)", counter)
        );

        // if the function call reverted
        if (success == false) {
            // if there is a return reason string
            if (returndata.length > 0) {
                // bubble up any reason for revert
                assembly {
                    let returndata_size := mload(returndata)
                    revert(add(32, returndata), returndata_size)
                }
            } else {
                revert("Function call reverted");
            }
        }
    }
    function getTokenName() public view returns (uint256)
    {
        return tokenName;
    }
    
}
```

**The event works perfect, but i cant change the state in ContractB.sol ...
https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x7fbacd6fa79d73b3b3233e955c9b95ae83efe2149002d1561c696061f6b1695e#eventlog**

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the code as text, so that it's easier for answerers to copy-paste and debug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that the event worked perfectly is proof that Keeper did its job properly. The problem here is the `delegatecall` itself.

When contract `A` executes `delegatecall` to contract `B`, `B`'s code is executed with contract `A`'s storage, `msg.sender` and `msg.value`. Storage, current address and balance still refer to the calling contract (contract `A`), only the code is taken from the called address (contract `B`).

In your case, `setTokenName` updates `ContractB`'s `tokenName` , ergo `ContractB`'s storage slot 0. The same storage slot at `Counter` smart contract is `uint256 public counter`. When you executed `delegatecall` you updated the `Counter`’s storage (`counter` variable) with `ContractB`’s `setTokenName` function logic.

Since you know the `ContractB`’s ABI why don’t you do something like this?

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./ContractB.sol";

contract Counter is KeeperCompatibleInterface {
    ContractB public contractB;
    uint256 public counter;

    constructor(ContractB _contractBAddress) {
        contractB = _contractBAddress;
    }

    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata) external override {
        counter = counter + 1;
        contractB.setTokenName(counter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```
    ContractB contractB = ContractB(contractBAddress);
    contractB.setTokenName(counter);
```

Documentation:
https://solidity-by-example.org/calling-contract/

Counter.sol

```
//Begin
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;

interface KeeperCompatibleInterface {
    function checkUpkeep(bytes calldata checkData) external returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory performData);
    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata performData) external;
}

contract Counter is KeeperCompatibleInterface {
    
    uint256 public counter;    // Public counter variable

    // Use an interval in seconds and a timestamp to slow execution of Upkeep
    //60 seconds
    uint public immutable interval;
    uint public lastTimeStamp;  //My counter was updated  
    
    //**
    address public contractBAddress;
    //**
    
    constructor(uint updateInterval,address _contractBAddress) {
      interval = updateInterval;
      lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
      counter = 0;
      contractBAddress=_contractBAddress;
    }

    function checkUpkeep(bytes calldata checkData) external view override returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory performData) {
        upkeepNeeded = (block.timestamp - lastTimeStamp) > interval;
        performData = checkData;
    }

    
    //When checkUpKeep its already to launch, this task is executed
    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata) external override {
        lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        counter = counter + 1;
        ContractB contractB = ContractB(contractBAddress);
        contractB.setTokenName(counter);
    }
    
}
```

ContractB.sol

```
contract ContractB {
    
    uint256 public tokenName = uint256(2);

    function setTokenName(uint256 _newName) external {                
      tokenName=_newName;
    }
    
    
    function getTokenName() public view returns (uint256)
    {
        return tokenName;
    }
    
}
```